# Color Search Database Design Schema

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a color search function utilizing php and mysql. The requirement of the search is that it needs to be fast, not use joins, and allow for 1-5 hex color inputs that query the database and return the "most accurate" results. By "most accurate" I mean that results will be reflective of the search input. I have a few pieces of data to help that such as the distance between the mapped color value (mapped against an array of pre-defined colors) and the original search input hex value (eg. `ff0000`).

The way the color search engine works is that you input 1-5 hex values (eg. #ff0000, #000000, #9ef855, etc), click search, and it searches the database to find images that contain the highest percentage of those colors. See [this color search](http://designspiration.net/colors/C73E87,F0B77A,E35218/) for reference to how a color search engine works. *Note: I built this one, but it has a completely different schema, which has scaling problems and cant add indexes because the number of colors is directly related to the number of table columns which is 120. Suggesting I use what I have built is out of the question for right now.*

The data in the database comes from measurements taken on images. Up to 5 colors are extracted from an image, and then each hex color value (`hex`) is mapped to the closest predefined hex value (`map_hex`). Both of these pieces of data as well as the following are stored in the database:

- media_id
- hex (actual true value from image measurement)
- map_hex (mapped value of the previous hex value)
- percentage (the amount of this color found in the image)
- distance (the distance between the true hex value and the mapped hex value)
- sequence (unix timestamp, for ordering)

Before a color search query gets sent to the database, it is mapped to a set of colors so we can use the mapping to do a direct lookup on `map_hex`. This to me seemed like a faster way than trying to do a range type of query.

As of right now I am experimenting with two database design schemas but both seem to have their own problems.

**Schema 1**

```
CREATE TABLE `media_has_colors` (
  `media_id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `hex` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `map_hex` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `percentage` double unsigned NOT NULL,
  `distance` double unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sequence` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`media_id`,`hex`),
  KEY `index_on_hex` (`hex`),
  KEY `index_on_percentage` (`percentage`),
  KEY `index_on_timestamp` (`sequence`),
  KEY `index_on_media_id` (`media_id`),
  KEY `index_on_mapping_distance` (`distance`),
  KEY `index_on_mapping_hex` (`map_hex`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Sample query:

```
SELECT sql_no_cache media_id, hex, map_hex, distance,
    avg(percentage) as percentage,
    SUM((IF(map_hex = '61615a',1,0)) + (IF(map_hex = '34362d',1,0)) + (IF(map_hex = 'dbd5dd',1,0))) as matchCount
FROM media_has_colors 
WHERE map_hex = '61615a' or map_hex = '34362d' or map_hex = 'dbd5dd'
GROUP BY media_id
ORDER BY matchCount DESC, distance, percentage DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

The First problem I see with schema 1 is that I am forced to use `group by` and `sum`. I'll admit I have not tested with a ton of records yet but it seems like it could get slow. On top of that I can't tell what `map_hex` values are matching (which is why I'm trying to get with `matchCount`.

**Schema 2**

```
CREATE TABLE `media_has_colors` (
  `media_id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `color_1_hex` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `color_2_hex` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `color_3_hex` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `color_4_hex` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `color_5_hex` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `color_1_map_hex` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `color_2_map_hex` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `color_3_map_hex` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `color_4_map_hex` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `color_5_map_hex` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `color_1_percent` double unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `color_2_percent` double unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `color_3_percent` double unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `color_4_percent` double unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `color_5_percent` double unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `color_1_distance` double unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `color_2_distance` double unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `color_3_distance` double unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `color_4_distance` double unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `color_5_distance` double unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sequence` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`media_id`),
  KEY `index_on_timestamp` (`sequence`),
  KEY `index_on_map_hex` (`color_1_map_hex`,`color_2_map_hex`,`color_3_map_hex`,`color_4_map_hex`,`color_5_map_hex`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This second schema is not as simple but it does avoid using group by only allowing 1 row per media. However, it seems to have the same problem of figuring out what `map_hex` values are matching. Here is a sample query:

```
SELECT sql_no_cache media_id, 
(IF(color_1_percent = '61615a',color_1_percent,1)) * 
(IF(color_2_percent = '34362d',color_2_percent,1)) * 
(IF(color_3_percent = 'dbd5dd',color_3_percent,1)) as percentage, 

(IF(color_1_distance = '61615a',color_1_distance,1)) + 
(IF(color_2_distance = '34362d',color_2_distance,1)) + 
(IF(color_3_distance = 'dbd5dd',color_3_distance,1)) as distance, 

color_1_map_hex, color_2_map_hex, color_3_map_hex, color_4_map_hex, color_5_map_hex, 

(IF(color_1_map_hex = '61615a',1,1)) + 
(IF(color_2_map_hex = '34362d',1,1)) + 
(IF(color_3_map_hex = 'dbd5dd',1,1)) as matchCount 

FROM media_has_colors 
WHERE   color_1_map_hex IN ('61615a','34362d','dbd5dd') OR 
        color_2_map_hex IN ('61615a','34362d','dbd5dd') OR 
        color_3_map_hex IN ('61615a','34362d','dbd5dd') 
ORDER BY matchCount DESC, distance, percentage DESC 
LIMIT 100;
```

You can see that there is a problem with calculating percentage and distance because the actual map_hex value may not appear in those specific columns.

Update: 
I don't need to know specifically what colors matched in the query but I do need to sort by which has the highest matches.

---

So my question is, **How can the schema or queries be fixed? If not, is there a better solution?**

Comment: It would probably greatly help if you show some sample values here and use cases here.  I am not really following the intent of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MikeBrant I've added sample hex values but they could be any hex number, as well as added a search example so you can understand how a color search functions. The intent is to build a color search engine that allows searching by multiple colors, not just one color.